# How to get visited routes Array

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a single page multistep form which is using a hash router. There are two things which I want to achieve:

1. If the user hit a direct URL of my route and if that particular route is not visited before redirect to home page route
2. In order to implement save progress in multistep form. How can we control browser back in the same sequence in which I visited the routes? ex. I completed the form till 20 steps (dynamic steps not sequential) and I saved the progress for the future. I came back and resume the application but there is no history of previous routes?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using with-router. I am getting a history object and methods to push it into the history but I need an array of history so that I can check if any of path exist in the array that means it's visited.